# Shared calendar is not listed when using CalendarApp.getAllCalendars() but found and accessible when using CalendarApp.getCalendarById()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, calendar

Shared calendar is not listed when using CalendarApp.getAllCalendars() but found and accessible when using CalendarApp.getCalendarById()

Is there any reason why specific calendar would not be listed when using CalendarApp.getAllCalendars() ?

Example:

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById( calendar ID );
Logger.log( cal.getName() );

var myCalendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
for( var q = 0 ; q < myCalendars.length ; q++ ){
    Logger.log( myCalendars[q].getName() +" > "+ myCalendars[q].getId());
}
```

Comment: Can you format a bit your code, and add the tags to your question telling what language you are using (for better audience)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Looks like hidden calendar will not show up in the All Calendar list and are not accessible by Name.
Here is a good solution:
[Access hidden Google calendars from CalendarApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383442/access-hidden-google-calendars-from-calendarapp)